# Avoid deep copy when adding attribute lxml.objectify

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

lxml.objectify's documentation states that any subtrees that are added as an attribute will be deep copied. Is there a way to avoid this? I am trying to mimic SQL-style relationships using XML, and I want any changes in a subtree object to change all of the attributes where that object is being set.

Comment: "mimic SQL-style relationships using XML" - what does that mean? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of Untangle, which doesn't deepcopy an element on attribute set. Thanks anyways.